# How to insert documents to couchdb in bulk by chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

How to insert/write documents to couchdb in bulk by chaincode? It seems that the chaincode shim library(https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim) doesn't have such API.

For reading documents, it seems that there is an API named "GetQueryResult"(https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim#ChaincodeStub.GetQueryResult). In the string parameter "query", we can construct bulk get request.

But for inserting/writing documents, is there any bulk API for chaincode? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When chaincode executes, each PutState() adds a key/value to the transaction's proposed writeset.  You can call PutState() multiple times in a chaincode, and the final set of keys/values will appear in the transaction's proposed writeset. Note that nothing is written to CouchDB at chaincode execution time.

Only when the transaction is submitted for ordering, will the transaction appear in a block that gets processed by all peers. Each peer validates the transactions and then applies the writesets of all valid transactions in the block to the CouchDB state database. Note that the state database commit is indeed using the CouchDB bulk update API (HTTP _bulk_docs), so you automatically get the desired bulk update performance in CouchDB.

If there are many key/value updates in the block, Fabric will actually group them into batches of 1000 (configurable using core.yaml maxBatchUpdateSize property) when committing to CouchDB to avoid any issues with excessively large payloads.  Finally, to ensure all writes appear to Fabric as an atomic commit, Fabric writes a final savepoint per block to the CouchDB state database and flushes the CouchDB data to disk. This ensures any chaincode executions get a consistent view of the state data, and ensures Fabric can recover from any peer crash with full data integrity.

Comment: Thanks. You mentioned "Note that the state database commit is indeed using the CouchDB bulk update API, so you automatically get the desired bulk update performance in CouchDB.". What does this mean? In couchdb, requests are made using HTTP, so multiple PutState() lead to multiple HTTP requests. What I mean by bulk inserting/writing is that I hope multiple key/value pairs inserting/updating can be included in only one HTTP request. To put it simple, only use one HTTP request to operate multiple key/value pairs.

Comment: And couchdb provides such API https://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/bulk-api.html?#db-bulk-docs , but how to invoke it in golang chaincode?

Comment: I clarified the answer for your follow-up question. Chaincode does not update CouchDB directly. Any updates are batched together in the later commit phase in a single HTTP _bulk_docs call to CouchDB. To understand the transaction flow in more detail, see https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/txflow.html.

Comment: I have read the link provided by you in detail, but it doesn't mention anything about bulk or batch. You mean that if chaincode's function contains multiple PutState() call, and a transaction which invoke this function will lead to combining these multiple PutState() call together into one _bulk_docs call to CouchDB? Are you sure about this?

Comment: Multiple PutState() calls in a transaction will result in a single _bulk_docs call to CouchDB (assuming Fabric v1.1 or later). But as my answer states, the call to CouchDB is made during the commit phase, not during the chaincode execution phase. I'm sure - I merged the code.

Comment: Hey Dave, quick clarification, if I have 5 transactions in one block, each transaction having 2 `putState()` calls on different keys, then when the block is committed, will there be 1 bulk write or 5 bulk writes?

Comment: Assuming all transactions target the same chaincode, and that all 5 transactions are valid, there will be 1 bulk write with 10 keys inserted/updated. There is one database per chaincode, and therefore one bulk write per chaincode per block.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to batch multiple transactions in one batch then it is not advisable to do so because if they are updating the same value then while looking at the history, the final change can only be tracked. So, it is better to submit individual transactions.

Comment: According to couchdb's documentation https://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/bulk-api.html#inserting-documents-in-bulk, Each time a document is stored or updated in CouchDB, the internal B-tree is updated. Bulk insertion provides efficiency gains in both storage space, and time, by consolidating many of the updates to intermediate B-tree nodes. So if I want to insert multiple different documents to couchdb, bulk inserting is more efficient. This means there is only one transaction which contains multiple documents inserting. But how to implement this in golang chaincode?

Comment: You are thinking it just as chaincode uploading data to couch db but that is not the case here, chaincode generates transactions which are executed, ordererd, validated and are stored in the form of blocks. State database where you implement the couchdb just determines the states of the assets. You may just directly upload your files to couchdb using golang queries but if you need blocks of those transactions, it is advisable to submit individual transactions.

Comment: I want to include multiple inserting/updating in one transaction. After peers endorse the transaction, the write-set which contains several writing operations will be generated. You mean that I can directly use shim API GetQueryResult https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim#ChaincodeStub.GetQueryResult to insert or update documents in couchdb? That is, parameter query string can actually be insert string or update string, am I right?

Comment: I think you need to look at this article (https://medium.com/@gatakka/problems-with-batching-in-hyperledger-fabric-chaincode-e1c348231645). It talks about the problem with batching the transactions.

Comment: It will be easier for you to understand if you thought it as transaction rather than documents.

Comment: Thanks very much, Bibek Koirala. I have already read the articles recommended by you. It is good. But the batch mentioned in the article is actually not the same thing with what I mean by bulk.

Comment: If you mean storing the bulk of document directly to the couchdb without making it transactions then why do you even need a chaincode. I think you should look to how a transaction is processed or how the client application and hyperledger network works and what is the function of chaincode.

Comment: What you talked about here is about the business or requirement. I think there can be such requirement. For example, a function in the chaincode can be named as "updateMultipleUsersValue". This function can invoke PutState() for several times, or invoke a bulk updating API to interact with couchdb. But now there is not bulk API.

Comment: While querying, you can directly look upto the state database but while you are writing to the state database,if you directly wrote it to couchdb without creating transactions and storing them in blocks, that data will be malicious. Therefore you need to append the transaction's block into the blockchain and the updated result will be seen in state database. Now if you need to update multiple users at once as a single transaction then it becomes a batch of transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question but by document, lets assume you mean a PDF file.
This has two functions, read a key value pair and write one. Nothing special here.

```
'use strict';
const { Contract } = require('fabric-contract-api');

Class SomeName extends Contract {

    async initLedger(ctx) { }

    async writeDocument(ctx, documentId, documentAsString) {
        await ctx.stub.putState(documentId, Buffer.from(documentAsString));
    };

    async getDocument(ctx, documentId) {
        const docAsBytes = await ctx.stub.getState(documentId);
        return carAsBytes.toString();
    };
}
```

Now comes the server side code

```
const { FileSystemWallet, Gateway } = require('fabric-network');

async main() {
    const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
    const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath); // can be wherever your path is

    const gateway = new Gateway();
    await gateway.connect(ccp, { wallet, identity: 'user1', discovery: { enabled: false }  });
    const network = await gateway.getNetwork('mychannel');
    // Get the contract from the network.
    const contract = network.getContract('SomeName');

    // Now over here lets assume you get the PDF file from a POST request using Multer
    // We get the PDF file as a buffer, then convert to a string and send it
    let pdfFile = req.file;

    await contract.submitTransaction('writeDocument', req.file.buffer.toString('utf-8);
}
```

and if you want to retrieve the PDF file

```
const getDocument = async (req, res, next) => {
    const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
    const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath); // can be wherever your path is

    const gateway = new Gateway();
    await gateway.connect(ccp, { wallet, identity: 'user1', discovery: { enabled: false }  });
    const network = await gateway.getNetwork('mychannel');
    // Get the contract from the network.
    const contract = network.getContract('SomeName');
    const pdfAsString= await contract.evaluateTransaction('getDocument', req.body.documentId);
    // Now do whatever with this
};
```

So I hope this answers your question regarding document upload, that being said its not a good practice to upload documents on a blockchain as it can slow down the transaction speed significantly.
In that case, you can store the document on a local server such as `mongoDB` and then refer a `sha256` hash of the document on the blockchain to cross check the authenticity of the document at a later stage.

Comment: Thanks very much for your so detailed code. What I mean by "document" is actually the terminology in the context of couchdb, which means JSON document, not the general document such as pdf, etc. My mistake to cause ambiguity. For general document, I think you idea of "store the document on a local server such as mongoDB and then refer a sha256 hash of the document on the blockchain" is good.

Comment: In couchdb, requests are made using HTTP, so multiple PutState() lead to multiple HTTP requests. What I mean by bulk inserting/writing is that I hope multiple key/value pairs inserting/updating can be included in only one HTTP request. To put it simple, only use one HTTP request to operate multiple key/value pairs. Couchdb API: https://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/bulk-api.html?#db-bulk-docs . Do you know how to invoke this in chaincode?

Comment: There is no way to perform bulk writes to couchDb using chaincode as of now afaik

Comment: Thanks, Varun Agarwal. This is exactly what I want to confirm. So far, the write can only be realized by PutState(), right? Could you confirm?

Comment: Yes the chaincode only accepts `putState()` but for queries there are multiple functions. If you want to change several documents in one transaction, you will need to write several `putState()`. I suggest reading this https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/readwrite.html and https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/txflow.html . In the latter at the end it says 'each valid transaction the write sets are committed to current state database' so no chance of batching.

Comment: EDIT: Dave is correct about the bulk write to couchDb. Refer to his answer for more info.

Comment: Are you sure? Is there any material about the bulk write mentioned by Dave?

Comment: I tried finding it myself, but reason I added this, is because I just met him in the Fabric chat channel and he is marked as an owner/ admin so I assume what he said is correct and thought I would let you know. Will need to ask for a source, from what I can find nothing in the docs explicitly mentions it